# PCIe hot reset vs slot reset

Tags: linux-kernel

I am working working on linux PCIe and NVMe driver. I came across a function in pci driver, ***pci_reset_bus()***, which does pci reset via slot or bus. I understand that reset via bus is "PCIe hot reset" which is defined in PCIe spec. But I am not sure what is pci slot reset (which is implemented by ***__pci_reset_slot()***).

Could anyone help me understanding this? and Also can I use this exported symbol i.e. **pci_reset_bus()**, for pci hot reset? I want to use this in my custom NVMe driver.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good tool("NVMeCraft") to handle some NVMe SSD. You can directly confirm your question with that tool, and can found the tool with googling.